# поиск по массиву c объектами

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов:

```js
[{
    "name": "Иван",
    "age": "12",
}, {
    "name": "Андрей",
    "age": "43",
}, {
    "name": "Ольга",
    "age": "14",
}, {
    "name": "Иван",
    "age": "32",
}, {
    "name": "Ольга",
    "age": "32",
}]
```

В объектах массива повторяются значения `name`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью js вернуть новый массив, содержащий только name но без повторений?

Comment: и что, никто не озаботился поиском и предолжением дубликатов? (а они на сайте есть стопроцентно)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin: 100500%-но :-)

Answer (score 2):

Способов много, но можно так

```js
let arr = [{ "name": "Иван", "age": "12", }, { "name": "Андрей", "age": "43", }, { "name": "Ольга", "age": "14", }, { "name": "Иван", "age": "32", }, { "name": "Ольга", "age": "32", }];

let result = [...new Set(arr.map(item=>item.name))];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: _"Способов много, но"_ этот самый лаконичный :)